# Combining two reports into one in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, report

I have two working reports / data-sources, but want to combine them into one.
I'm not too sure about which sections should go where, and what needs to go inside what bracket.

Some help regarding combining these into one report would be appreciated, the link field between both reports is the job.job_number field.

Edit:  What I would like to see at the end is a report that gives me the following headings:

```
ALL FROM REPORT / DATASOURCE ONE
Job.Job_number                       410000378
job.site_code                        1372
job.job_entry_date                   31/01/2019 17:45:23
job.actual_comp_date                 04/06/2019
central_site.site_name               HIGH STREET, NEWPORT
area.area_name                       NEWPORT
zone_1_area_check                    ZONE 1 AREA
day_logged                           Thu
week_on_site                         5
job_type.job_type_code               FLY1
job_type.job_type_name               FLYTIP ZONE 1 AREA
Gang_Photos                          Photos Linked
Photo_Count                          2
Photo Check                          Pass
Arrived_on_time_check                Pass
KPI_PASS_FAIL                        Pass
KPI_PENALTY_INSTANCES                0
KPI_STATUS_CHECK                     Pass
JOB_KPI                              KPI 2 - FLY TIPPING
KPI_POINTS                           25
Week_dashboard                       Current Week
Month_dashboard                      Current Month
Quarter_dashboard                    Current Quarter

ALL FROM DATA-SOURCE TWO:
clock_start                          01/02/2019 08:00:00
target_time                          01/02/2019 12:00:00
priority.priority_code               GC06
```

First report / data-source code:

```
select
job.job_number,
job.job_entry_date,
job.site_code,
central_site.site_name,
area.area_name as Parish,
JOB.JOB_ENTRY_DATE as Job_logged,
priority.priority_code,
priority.priority_name,
job.target_comp_date as Target_On_Site,
job.actual_START_date as Actual_On_Site,
JOB.actual_COMP_DATE as Job_Completed_Time,

CASE
WHEN   central_site.site_code in     
                                ('456','1372','1373','1426','1432','2251',
                                '3202','3206','4017','9978','9979','9980',
                                '9981','9982','9983','9984','9985','9986',
                                '9987','9988','9989','9990','9991','9992',
                                '9993','9994','9995','9996','9997','9998',
                                '9999')
THEN 'Zone 1 Area' 
ELSE '' 
END as ZONE_1_AREA_CHECK,


TO_CHAR(job.job_entry_date, 'Dy') as DAY_LOGGED,
TO_CHAR(job.actual_start_date, 'IW') as WEEK_ON_SITE,
job_type.job_type_code,
job_type.job_type_name,

-- CHECK TO SEE IF 2 PHOTOS HAVE BEEN TAKEN ON JOB
CAST(CASE WHEN document_link.entity_key IS NULL THEN 'No Photos' ELSE 
'Photos Linked' END as VARCHAR (20)) as gang_photos,
(SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) AND
document_link.entity_type = 'JOB' AND
document_link.document_notes LIKE 'Photo added by_%' ) as Photo_count,
CASE 
WHEN ROUND ((SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) AND
document_link.entity_type = 'JOB'),2) >=2 then 'Pass' else 'FAIL' end as 
Photo_Check, 

-- kpi tracker
CASE
WHEN job.actual_start_date is null AND current_date < job.target_comp_date 
THEN 'Not arrived on site yet'
WHEN job.actual_start_date is null AND current_date > job.target_comp_date 
THEN 'FAIL (2)'
when job.actual_start_date <= job.target_comp_date then 'Pass'
when job.actual_start_date > job.target_comp_date then 'FAIL'
ELSE 'Overdue' END as Arrived_on_time_check,

-- KPI arrive on site and 2 photos check
CASE
WHEN  job.actual_start_date <= job.target_comp_date AND 
ROUND ((SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) AND 
document_link.entity_type = 'JOB'),2) >=2 then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end as 
KPI_PASS_FAIL,


-- KPI Instances of penalty
CASE
-- arrived on site in time and 2+ photos = 0 penalty  (pass)
WHEN  job.actual_start_date <= job.target_comp_date AND 
ROUND ((SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) 
AND document_link.entity_type = 'JOB'),2) >=2 then '0' 

-- arrived on time but no photos attached = 1 penalty  (FAIL PHOTOS)
WHEN  job.actual_start_date <= job.target_comp_date AND 
ROUND ((SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) 
AND document_link.entity_type = 'JOB'),2) <=1 then '1' 

--arrived on site late BUT 2+ PHOTOS = manual calculation  (FAIL TIME)
WHEN  job.actual_start_date > job.target_comp_date AND 
ROUND ((SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) 
AND document_link.entity_type = 'JOB'),2) >=2  THEN 'Manual Calculation - 
Time Fail'

-- ARRIVED LATE AND NOT ENOUGH PHOTOS  (FAIL TIME AND PHOTOS)
WHEN  job.actual_start_date > job.target_comp_date AND
ROUND ((SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) 
AND document_link.entity_type = 'JOB'),2) <=1 THEN 'Manual Calculation - 
Time and Photo Fail'

 else 'Check' end as KPI_PENALTY_INSTANCES,


-- KPI STATUS CHECK
CASE
-- arrived on site in time and 2+ photos = 0 penalty  (pass)
WHEN  job.actual_start_date <= job.target_comp_date AND 
ROUND ((SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) 
AND document_link.entity_type = 'JOB'),2) >=2 then 'PASS' 

-- arrived on time but no photos attached = 1 penalty  (FAIL PHOTOS)
WHEN  job.actual_start_date <= job.target_comp_date AND 
ROUND ((SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) 
AND document_link.entity_type = 'JOB'),2) <=1 then 'FAIL - PHOTOS' 

--arrived on site late BUT 2+ PHOTOS = manual calculation  (FAIL TIME)
WHEN  job.actual_start_date > job.target_comp_date AND 
ROUND ((SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) 
AND document_link.entity_type = 'JOB'),2) >=2  THEN 'FAIL - ARRIVED LATE'

-- ARRIVED LATE AND NOT ENOUGH PHOTOS  (FAIL TIME AND PHOTOS)
WHEN  job.actual_start_date > job.target_comp_date AND
ROUND ((SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) 
AND document_link.entity_type = 'JOB'),2) <=1 THEN 'FAIL - TIME AND PHOTOS'

WHEN job.actual_START_date is NULL then 'FAIL - ARRIVED TIME BLANK'

else 'Check' end as KPI_STATUS_CHECK,


-- JOB KPI ATTRIBUTE LOOK UP IN GJOB TABLE
(SELECT attribute_value.attrib_value_name FROM attribute_value WHERE 
attribute_value.attrib_type_code = 'GJOB' 
AND attribute_value.attrib_value_code = job_type.job_type_code) as JOB_KPI,

-- JOB KPI PENALTY POINTS LOOK UP IN GJOB TABLE
(SELECT attribute_value.attrib_value_nom FROM attribute_value WHERE 
attribute_value.attrib_type_code = 'GJOB' 
AND attribute_value.attrib_value_code = job_type.job_type_code) as 
KPI_POINTS,



-- FIELDS FOR USE IN DASHBOARD WIDGETS
CASE
when job.actual_comp_date >= trunc(trunc(SYSDATE,'IW')-1,'IW') AND 
job.actual_comp_date <=trunc(SYSDATE,'IW') then 'Previous Week'
when job.actual_comp_date >=trunc(SYSDATE,'IW') AND job.actual_comp_date <= 
SYSDATE then 'Current Week'
else ''
end as Week_Dashboard,

CASE
when job.actual_comp_date >= trunc(trunc(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'MM') AND 
job.actual_comp_date <=trunc(SYSDATE,'MM') then 'Previous Month'
when job.actual_comp_date >=trunc(SYSDATE,'MM') AND job.actual_comp_date <= 
SYSDATE then 'Current Month'
else ''
end as Month_Dashboard,

CASE
when job.actual_comp_date >= trunc(trunc(SYSDATE,'IW')-1,'Q') AND 
job.actual_comp_date <=trunc(SYSDATE,'Q') then 'Previous Quarter'
when job.actual_comp_date >=trunc(SYSDATE,'Q') AND job.actual_comp_date <= 
SYSDATE then 'Current Quarter'
else ''
end as Quarter_Dashboard

from
job
left join enquiry on job.job_number = enquiry.job_number
left join defect on job.job_number = defect.job_number
left join defect_type on defect_type.defect_type_code = defect.defect_type
inner join central_site on job.site_code = central_site.site_code
inner join area on central_site.area_code = area.area_code
left join central_enquiry on central_enquiry.enquiry_number = 
enquiry.enquiry_number
left join enquiry_cust_link on central_enquiry.enquiry_number = 
enquiry_cust_link.enquiry_number
left join enquiry_subject on enquiry_subject.subject_code = 
central_enquiry.subject_code
left join type_of_service on type_of_service.service_code = 
enquiry_subject.service_code
inner join priority on priority.priority_code = job.priority_code
inner join JOB_STATUS_LOG on JOB.JOB_NUMBER = JOB_STATUS_LOG.JOB_NUMBER 
and job.job_log_number = job_status_log.job_log_number
inner join JOB_STATUS on JOB_STATUS.STATUS_CODE = JOB_STATUS_LOG.STATUS_CODE
inner join job_type on job_type.job_type_key = job.job_type_key
inner join priority on priority.priority_code = job.priority_code

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT
job.job_number,
document_link.entity_key,
(SELECT COUNT(document_link.entity_key) FROM document_link WHERE 
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) AND
document_link.entity_type = 'JOB' AND
document_link.document_notes LIKE 'Photo added by_%' ) as Photo_count
FROM
job
LEFT OUTER JOIN
document_link
ON
document_link.entity_key =CAST( job.job_number as VARCHAR (15)) AND
document_link.entity_type = 'JOB' AND
document_link.document_notes LIKE 'Photo added by_%') document_link
ON
document_link.job_number = job.job_number

where
job_status_log.allocated_officer = 'IDVE' and
job_status_log.status_code in ('5100','5200','5300','5400') 

order by
job.job_number
```

Second Report / Data-Source Code:

```
select job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, clock_start, 
target_comp_date,
case
when to_char(target_time, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
and floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
then target_time + 2 + 63/24
when floor((target_time - trunc(target_time)) * 24) >= 17
then target_time + 15/24
else target_time
end as target_time

from (
select job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, clock_start, 
TARGET_COMP_DATE,
CASE 
WHEN PRIORITY_CODE IN ('GC01','GC02','GC03','GC04','GC05','GC06','GC07') 
THEN
clock_start 
+ case priority_code 
when 'GC01' then 1 
when 'GC02' then 2 
when 'GC03' then 0.5
when 'GC04' then 1 
when 'GC05' then 2 
when 'GC06' then 4
when 'GC07' then 24

end
/ 24 

ELSE
TARGET_COMP_DATE END as target_time

from              (
select job_number, priority_code, job_entry_date, target_comp_date,
case
when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Fri'
and floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) >= 17
then trunc(job_entry_date) + 80/24
when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sat'
then trunc(job_entry_date) + 56/24
when to_char(job_entry_date, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') = 'Sun'
or floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) >= 17
then trunc(job_entry_date) + 32/24
when floor((job_entry_date - trunc(job_entry_date)) * 24) < 8
then trunc(job_entry_date) + 8/24
else job_entry_date
end as clock_start
from job
  )
)
```

Comment: By "report", are you talking about Oracle Reports?

Comment: They are data-sources in the program that when run produce the information that can then be exported into Excel

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the sample input? Can you slim down your queries to produce a simplified test case? Please edit your question to include that test case. By doing that, you give us a much better chance of being able to help.

Comment: Thank you - have added what the expected output should be like and will try and add data for a test case.

Comment: Sounds like you need to join the two queries together, somehow. How are the queries linked (i.e. what are the join conditions)?

Comment: There's no link between the two queries at the moment - I don't know how to do that.  But each query would each have job.job_number in both so could be linked together on that as the primary key.